# android.view.textclassifier doesn't work on android 13

Tags: java, android

Any idea on this issue?
TextClassifier api used to work before I updated to android 13. Tested on other android 13 devices - same issue.

This code example bellow was working before update to "13", tried all the other implementations but no luck((

```
TextClassificationManager manager = (TextClassificationManager) getSystemService(TEXT_CLASSIFICATION_SERVICE);
        TextClassifier classifier = manager.getTextClassifier();

        TextLinks.Request textRequest = new TextLinks.Request.Builder(text)
                .setEntityConfig(TextClassifier.EntityConfig.createWithExplicitEntityList(Arrays.asList(TextClassifier.TYPE_ADDRESS)))
                .build();
        TextLinks links = classifier.generateLinks(textRequest);
classifier.classifyText(text, 0, text.length(), new LocaleList(Locale.US))
```

UPDATE: Only address detection stopped working. All other textTypes can be detected, such as phone numbers and urls.

Comment: How did you understand that the feature does not work? And what exactly is not working `classifyText` method?

Comment: Exactly `generateLinks()` method isn't working. On android 12 and below this method generates links(in my case addresses), but when I updated my devices to android 13 it just stopped working

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified the version of your SDK? Is it SDK 33? Please change it to SDK 32 and give it a try. It should function properly.

Android studio>>buildgradle

```
android {
    **compileSdk 32** // Here

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        **targetSdk 32** // And Here
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```

And also try the below code.

```
 **dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'**
```

Comment: Yes my sdk version was 33. Unfortunately changing these properties didn't help(

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read in the documentation of [TextClassifier#generateLinks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/textclassifier/TextClassifier#generateLinks(android.view.textclassifier.TextLinks.Request)) you should call it from a worker thread.

> NOTE: Call on a worker thread.

Do you call it from the worker thread?

Comment: Yes. But no luck, it can detect phone numbers, urls, but can't detect map addresses anymore on android 13